# AJAX: Preventing Python Code Automation onClick()

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I'm trying to automate running reports through a third party website using Python and selenium. I get to the point where I've filled all the fields and selected all the options. When I run *`browser.find_element_by_id('submitBtn').click()* or *.submit()* the "Run Report" button, I get taken to a page where I'm told I do have not have authorization to run the report--it seems AJAX code was written to hinder automation. Is there anyway around this? I run lots of reports monthly and am trying to save time and reduce errors by using Python and VBA.

```
 <input type="submit" id="submitBtn"onclick="
     disableForms(false, isAsynchronousReportRun(this.form)); 
     if (validate() === false) {
         return false;
     }
     disableForm(document.forms[0]);
     return generateReportByOutputFormat(document.forms[0],
     document.forms[0].output_format_type, true);"
 value="Run Report" />
```

The validate function is below:

```
function validate() {
    var shouldSubmit = false;
    $("#state").val("verify");

    $.ajax({
        url: $("#form1").attr("action"),
        data: $("#form1").serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            if (response === "") {
                $("#state").val("run_report");
                shouldSubmit = printWarningMessage(document.form1);
            } else {
                displayErrorAndEmptyResults(response);
            }
         },
        async: false,
        type: "POST"
    });

   return shouldSubmit;
}
```

Comment: Find if the 3rd party has an API, which will legally allow you to do this.

Comment: Talk with your devs. Testability is a feature in itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't have API access. I'm going to try using Python's mouse GUI automation--not perfect but may work.